# control microsoft powerpoint (running slideshows, etc.) using java

Tags: java, powerpoint

I working in java currently and I want to control a microsoft powerpoint slideshow (moving back and forth in a slideshow, starting and exiting a slideshow etc.) using java code. Is there any API (or any other way) for doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This link (one of the first when googling "java powerpoint api") looks promising: http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/other_examples/Powerpoint_from_Java.htm

Comment: Note that j-integra isn't free - rather expensive actually!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can comply with the LGPL, [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) looks like just what you need. JACOB is a Java-COM bridge, which allows you to interface with Windows programs.